# How to calculate age from a string date?

Tags: php, symfony, date, datetimepicker

I am using `bootstrap-material-datetimepicker` on my Symfony form so the user can select his birthday.

The `datetimepicker` returns a string for example `"Saturday 16 May 2020"`.

I want to calculate the `age` of the user (int number) from that string birthday!

How can I calculate the age? 
Is there a way to make the datetime return date or int instead of the string ?

The code of my form :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}

        {{ form_start(form, {attr: {novalidate: 'novalidate'}}) }}

               <div class="form-line">
                    {{ form_widget(form.birthday,  {'attr': {'class': 'datepicker form-control', 'placeholder': 'Date of Birth'} }) }}      
               </div>

         {{ form_rest(form) }}
         {{ form_end(form) }}        


{% endblock %}
```

The code of the entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $birthday;

public function getBirthday(): ?string
{
    return $this->birthday;
}

public function setBirthday(?string $birthday): self
{
    $this->birthday = $birthday;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: change your form so that birthday is BirthdayType https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/birthday.html . you'll get a datetime that way. also set the column type to date and actually store it in a date column. storing a string in db is just insane, sry.

Comment: after that, you can use `date_diff` and fetch the years field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got 2 choices:

- Change the birthday to a field of type datetime and use BirthdayType
  in your form. Then you'll have to format the field when you want to
  show it as string with `->format('Y-m-d')` in controller or using
  twig's `|date('Y-m-d')` filter as `$user->getBirthday()` will give you back a DateTime Object.
- Create a new DateTime Object from the string in that field when you
  want to calculate the age (ie: `new \DateTime($user->getBirthday()`).

When you have your DateTime Object all you need is to create a new one for "today" and calculate the difference from there using DateTime Object's [`diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.diff.php) method or PHP's [`date_diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.date-diff.php) function.